# What is the best way in tab system with $_GET method

Tags: get, tabs

I am trying to make tab sistem. So i am reading browser $_GET values and displaying tab contents.

```
www.site.com/product-1/
www.site.com/product-1/?tab-1
www.site.com/product-1/?tab-2
www.site.com/product-1/?tab-3
```

And here is PHP:

```
if ( isset($_GET['tab-1']) ):
    //tab-1 content here
endif;

if ( isset($_GET['tab-2']) ):
    //tab-2 content here
endif;

if ( isset($_GET['tab-3']) ):
    //tab-3 content here
endif;

if ( empty($_GET) ):
    //default content
endif;
```

But i am blocked here. What happens if different $_GET value. If get value is different, for example **?asd** it must show default content.

Is this true way? Or can anyone suggest me any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be better to give a parameter to your variable tab

```
www.site.com/product-1/
www.site.com/product-1/?tab=1
www.site.com/product-1/?tab=2
www.site.com/product-1/?tab=3
```

and checking it on your php code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['tab'])) {
    switch ($_GET['tab']) {
        case '1':
            //tab-1 content here
            break;
        case '2':
            //tab-2 content here
            break;
        case '3':
            //tab-3 content here
            break;
        default:
            //default content1
            break;
    }
}else{
       //default content2, but you are sure that the url will be hacked
}
?>
```

so ?tab=asd will go on default content1
and ?asd will go on default content2

by the way,
i'm a kind of suspicious with urls, i have been learned 
"never trust user input"
so i would use htmlspecialchars($_GET['tab']) instead of just $_GET['tab'] to avoid XXS exploit

Comment: Thank you. But i am using it with foreach loop. array('tab-slug-1', 'tab-slug-2')